# How to relocate, re-install, and re-publish every packages in a dependency jar using maven plugins?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin

Here is a real case I have encountered on an apache project:

Project `spark` has a diamond dependency:

```
spark -> hive v1.2.1
spark -> avro -> hive v2.3.0
```

hive v1.2.1 & v2.3.0 use the same package names (org.apache.hive), which causes jar hell.

Due to this concern, I want to relocate everything (both packages & classes) in hive v1.2.1 to another path (spark-project.org.apache.hive), bundle the relocated things into a new jar, re-install the new jar into local .m2 repository, and (optional) re-publish the new jar into remote maven central channel.

So far, I've found none of the maven plugin capable of doing this: The maven shade plugin can do the relocation, however:

1. it won't re-install & re-publish the new jar
2. the new jar contains all packages in my own project, not only packages in a dependency
3. as a result of 2, if multiple dependencies all contain the package `org.apache.spark`, then everything inside the package in all the dependencies will be relocated, while in reality only 1 of them should be relocated.

So I'm wondering if there is a better option. Due to the flexible deployment requirement of this project I'm not allowed to use any customised classloaders, including those invented by OSGi

Comment: Questions: Are you encountering any issues with this, or is it just a concern? Is it not sufficient to just exclude the dependency in your pom?

Comment: It is impossible, both hive v1.2.1 & v2.3.0 are used somewhere and in both cases they can't use the other versions

Comment: Maybe you can update the code so that all code works with 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Not possible in reasonable time